# How to call procedure from another procedure in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have two procedure as **Procedure A** and **Procedure B.**

Procedure B:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
PROCEDURE B(document_id in  varchar2,
                                 display_type   in  varchar2,
                                 document   in out  NOCOPY varchar2,
                                 document_type  in out  NOCOPY varchar2,
                                 oracle_id in varchar2);

END pkg ;
/
```

I am using procedure B in Procedure A

```
l_document_id := 'PLSQL:pkg.B(null,null,null,null,21)/' || v_seq_no;
```

Execution of Procedure A get errors

> procedure/callback 'pkg.B(null,null,null,null,21)' contains illegal character

Comment: Please share both procedures, or dummy procedures that illustrate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using it suggests that `B` should be a **function**, not a procedure.

Or, if it is a procedure, then it should have an `OUT` parameter which will be returned into `A`'s local variable `l_document_id`, such as

```
pkg_B(null, null, null, null, 21, l_document_id)
                                  -------------
                                    this
```

Also, you should remove single quotes while calling *it* (whatever "it" is, procedure or function):

```
No : 'pkg.B(null,null,null,null,21)/'      || v_seq_no     
Yes:  pkg.B(null,null,null,null,21) || '/' || v_seq_no
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two variables to get the document and type back from the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a AS
  v_document VARCHAR2(30000);
  v_document_type VARCHAR2(30000);
BEGIN
  pkg.b (123, 'display type x', v_document, v_document_type, 123456);
END a;
```

Comment: The error appears only when I call the PROCEDURE B with arguments. If I call it without argument there is no error

Comment: I don't see how you can call it wthout arguments (aka parameters). The procedure requires five of them: document_id, display_type, document, document_type, and oracle_id.

Comment: Yes, this line successfully execute -> l_document_id := 'PLSQL:pkg.B/' || v_seq_no;

Comment: The line `l_document_id := 'PLSQL:pkg.B/' || v_seq_no;` does not call the procedure. It merely fills the string `l_document_id` with something like `'PLSQL:pkg.B/123456'`.